# Gravity forms get uploaded file path

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a gravity form that uploads a file into entries. i need to get the uploaded path after submission.
Here is my existing code:

```
add_action( 'gform_pre_submission_13', 'pre_submission_handler' );
function pre_submission_handler( $form ) {
         //get uploaded file url path ( http:// )
}
```

Some documentation would be helpful

Comment: i think this is what im looking for https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_after_submission/ but have no idea how to implement

Answer (score 6):

**How to get the file upload path after submission:**

You are using `gform_pre_submission` which is the wrong hook, you need to use `gform_after_submission`.

In your code, instead of adding the action to `gform_pre_submission_13` (where 13 is the ID of your form), you should use `gform_after_submission_13`.

Refer to this link for more info: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_after_submission/

**My sample code to get the uploaded path after submission (where the form ID is 1 and the upload field ID is 2):**

```
function md_gform_after_submission_1( $entry, $form ) {
 
  $upload_path = GFFormsModel::get_upload_path( $entry[ 'form_id' ] );
  $upload_url = GFFormsModel::get_upload_url( $entry[ 'form_id' ] );
 
  $filename = str_replace( $upload_url, $upload_path, $entry[ '2' ] ); // 2 is the ID of the image field
  echo "<p><b>Your File has been stored here: </b> $filename</p>";
  
}
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'md_gform_after_submission_1', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: Does it work for multiple file upload settings?